# Improving performance of Pandas keyword search

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to analyze some text data and search for keywords. I have the text data in a pandas dataframe, and I have the keywords in another dataframe. What will be the most efficient method to search the text data dataframe for each item in the keyword dataframe? I'm trying to avoid looping if possible, since I know that can get pretty horrible performance. I thought about writing a function which I could then use dataframe.apply on the source dataframe, but I can't figure out a way to get around having to loop through the second dataframe and look for each keyword in my source...

I've included an example below of the source data setup, as well as a mockup of what my resultant dataframe should look like. Score would be how many of the keywords are in the text for that row. Thanks in advance!!

```
#%% Setup
import pandas as pd

source_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "IDNumber": [4, 5, 6, 7],
        "Text": [
            "Number 4 has a cell phone, lightsaber, and a tablet",
            "Number 5 has a burrito",
            "Number 6 has a lightsaber and the senate",
            "",
        ],
    }
)

keyword_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Keyword": [
            "lightsaber",
            "microphone",
            "senate",
            6,
        ]
    }
)

#%% Trying to come up with something that results in
#   IDNumber    Text                                                    Score
# 0 4           Number 4 has a cell phone, lightsaber, and a tablet.    1
# 1 5           Number 5 has a burrito                                  0
# 2 6           Number 6 has a lightsaber and the senate                3
# 3 7                                                                   0
```

Comment: Why is "Number 6 has a lightsaber and the senate" not 3 if it contains 6, lightsaber, and senate?

Comment: My bad, edited to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant 3 instead of 2 as score for IDNumber 6, here is a solution:

```py
source_df['Score'] = source_df['Text'].str.findall(
    '|'.join(keyword_df['Keyword'].astype('str').tolist())
).str.len()
```

Comment: Ah nice catch; I included the 6 just to illustrate that some things might be numbers, but it does indeed resolve to 3. I'll fix original. This works for me and seems pretty performant. Thanks!!!!